# Why do I get an error if the App is wrapped in Provider?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-testing-library

Why do I get an error if the App is wrapped in Provider? Is there anything else you need to add or change?

Error: "could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a @Provider@"

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from './redux/redux-store';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';

test('App renders', () => {
  render(<App />);
});
```

index.ts file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from './redux/redux-store';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do wrap App in a Provider in your root render. But is not the case  in the test.

```
test('App renders', () => {
  render(<Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>);
});
```

Comment: now i get "useRoutes() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component"

Comment: In the same way your are wrapping App with BrowserRouter in the root render but not in your test. I would recommend moving both BrowserRouter and Provider directly into your app

Comment: So in the root index.ts is already wrapped, maybe you mean in the test file?

Comment: Yes, it is, thank you! It's all working!

Comment: Is it really necessary to wrap it that way every time?

Comment: It is neccessary for any component that require those provider, in this case any component that is using redux will require to be wrapped in a Provider